# loading postcodes from a text file using javascript to show on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables, maps

Just to start I am not very good with Javascript and completely out of my depth.

However I have a work project to complete when I need to display multiple postcodes on a Google map for monitoring purposes.

I have found this :

http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/showthread.php?p=20622530

and was able to add them from a predefined variable but not from the text file.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Jonathan

Comment: So your main question is how to get data from a text file using javascript?

Comment: thats right so that i can display in google maps

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file ?